# Why does this Unit Test pass when my database field is_busy is true?

Tags: java, database, http, jdbc

[image: Breakpoint screenshot]

[image: Debug screenshot]

```
public void getAllEmployeesTest() throws IOException {
    HttpResponse response = http.get("http://localhost:8087/employee");
    List<Employee> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedList.add(new Employee(2, "Yashwant", "Chavan", 30, false));
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<Employee> actualList = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), listType);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList,actualList);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is executed? No @Test a the top of the method

Comment: a lot could be happening between your REST service and the DB. you will have to debug your service implementation.

Comment: Put breakpoint before you assertEquals and check that the objects are really different (all the attributes), if so check if your equals() method in Employee is correctly implemented

Comment: @Test is above, i mean something wrong with my JsonProperty "busy"